# How to get raw page source (not generated source) from c#

Tags: c#, html

The goal is to get the raw source of the page, I mean do not run the scripts or let the browsers format the page at all. for example: suppose the source is `<table><tr></table>` after the response, I don't want get `<table><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>`, how to do this via c# code?

More info: for example, type "view-source:http://feeds.gawker.com/kotaku/full" in the browser's address bar will give u a xml file, but if you just call "http://feeds.gawker.com/kotaku/full" it will render a html page, what I want is the xml file. hope this is clear.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information - where are you running code? Which page are you trying to get the source for? Please provide more context.

Comment: Err, you just make an HTTP request for it. It usually takes special effort to parse markup, and even more to run client side scripts on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, but it's not really clear what you actually want.

```
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    var source = wc.DownloadString("http://google.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean when rendering your own page. You can get access the the raw page content using a [`ResponseFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx), or by overriding page render. I would question your motives for doing this though.

Scripts run client-side, so it has no bearing on any c# code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what is actually being sent over the wire.

*disclaimer: I think Fiddler is amazing*