# How to get the raw HTML source code for a page by using Ruby or Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, raw-data

I'm using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) (Ruby Xpath library) to grep contents on web pages. Then I found problems with some web pages, such as Ajax web pages, and that means when I view source code I won't be seeing the exact contents such as `<table>`, etc.

How can I get the HTML code for the actual content?

Comment: im not sure what you are asking here. are you asking how use `Nokogiri` to view generated source code of a web page?  Basically, you are trying to view the source code that includes any elements that AJAX has made to the DOM?

Comment: You can see example : http://capital.sec.or.th/webapp/corp_fin2/daily59.php

Comment: On the page you will see the data table and then you right click to view source you won't be to got the data table (because php include scription or etc.) and then you use nokogiri to grep content you cound't get the whole of content.

I found this link that exactly what i mean but in C#
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526569/how-to-get-raw-page-source-not-generated-source-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use Nokogiri at all if you want the raw source of a web page. Just fetch the web page directly as a string, and then do not feed that to Nokogiri. For example:

```
require 'open-uri'
html = open('http://phrogz.net').read
puts html.length #=> 8461
puts html        #=> ...raw source of the page...
```

If, on the other hand, you want the post-JavaScript-modified contents of a page (such as an AJAX library that executes JavaScript code to fetch new content and change the page), then you can't use Nokogiri. You need to use Ruby to control a web browser (e.g. read up on Selenium or Watir).

Comment: +1 for Selenium or Watir. If you don't want to actually see the browser window, you can use those with HtmlUnit, a Java-based headless browser with JavaScript support. PhantomJS is another such tool, but I'm not sure yet how well it integrates with Ruby testing tools. (Unfortunately, in my experience HtmlUnit is very slow. I'm not sure if I've misconfigured it, or if that's just the way it is.)

Comment: I can speak for PhantomJS. Using Poltergeist and Capybara you can integrate it very nicely into a Ruby testing environment, or other app functions for that matter.