# Is there a way to get the raw HTML from Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I've seen the "[How to get the raw HTML source code for a page by using Ruby or Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919422/how-to-get-the-raw-html-source-code-for-a-page-by-using-ruby-or-nokogiri)" which uses something like this:

```
file = open("index.html")
puts file.read
page = Nokogiri::HTML(file)
```

But it seems to move the read point to the end of the file so that Nokogiri can't read the file anymore. If I swap the `read` and Nokogiri call:

```
file = open("index.html")
puts file.read
page = Nokogiri::HTML(file)
```

The file is no longer output. I'd like to be able to query Nokogiri for the HTML it used originally, so that I can do my own extra parsing on the raw source. Ideally, I'd like something like

```
file = open("index.html")
page = Nokogiri::HTML(file)
raw_html = page.html
```

Note: I've also tried `page.to_html`, but it seems to change the formatting slightly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You usually pass a `File` instance so it can be processed by chunks, but [passing a string is also ok](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/HTML/Document.html#M000195):

```
html = File.read("index.html")
page = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
page_html = page.html
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I didn't realize you could give it a HTML string. Thanks.

Comment: @neval: yep, `string_or_io` is how it's referenced at the docs. Python usually does the same for potentially big inputs (if you send a file-like object, and the algorithm allows it, it will be read by chunks).

Comment: Got it. I'm still just starting with Ruby and Nokogiri and don't know much of anything. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Just as a FYI: You can also ask Nokogiri to return the HTML (or XML if that's what you're working with) of the document after Nokogiri has parsed it, or after modifications:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<head><body>foo</body></head>')
puts doc.to_html
```

Which will output in pry:

```
[4] (pry) main: 0> puts doc.to_html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
<body>foo</body>
</html>
```

Notice that Nokogiri did some fixups to make the HTML "more-better".

Comment: The OP wanted the contents unchanged. From the question: "Note: I've also tried page.to_html, but it seems to change the formatting slightly."

Comment: Correct. This wasn't meant as an answer, just to provide additional information that can be useful later. That's why it says, "Just as a FYI".